# Selecting features randomly from a given matrix using python

Tags: python, matrix, random

I have a 6 by 6 matrix created using python. From the 36 values included in the matrix, i want to select any 10 values (it should select the values randomly, not by specifying the position) from the matrix which are non-zero and the selected 10 values should be printed at the end. Please help me with the code in python

```
 import numpy as np
 from numpy import random
 #import Dataframe.sample as df 
 rows = 6
 cols = 6 
 a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(220,376, size=(rows,cols)))
 print (a)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!! please provide the code you tried

Comment: Flatten the matrix to a list an use `random.sample`? If it's a `numpy` matrix, there may be other options, but this should still work. Also, should repeated values be allowed?

Comment: Actually, i have only created the 6 by 6 matrix. The code is

import numpy as np
from numpy import random
#import Dataframe.sample as df


rows = 6
cols = 6
a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(220,376, size=(rows,cols)))
print (a)


now i want to select 10 random values which are inside the matrix. I have no idea about the code for it.

Comment: No need of repeating the same value unless the same value is included in two or more places in the 6 by 6 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can access a matrix with `matrix[y][x]` and generate random indexes with the package random. Random can be used with `import random`. After it is imported you can generate a random index with `x = random.randint(0,5)`.

A short example:

```
import random
for i in range(10): #10 times
    x = random.randint(0,5) #index X
    y = random.randint(0,5) #index Y
    value = matrix[y][x] #get the value
    print(value) #print the value
```

Please note the name of my matrix is `matrix`, yours is named `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a 6x6 matrix:

```
x = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)
```

Then you can use [random.choice()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) on the matrix collapsed into one dimension ([flatten()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html))

```
np.random.choice(x.flatten(), 10, replace=False)
```

to get 10 random elements.

---

For a `np.matrix`, like in your case it changes and I don't know a direct method.    What you can do is as follows.
You select the indices.

```
selected = np.random.choice(a.shape[0]*a.shape[1], 10, replace=False)
# e.g., array([[25, 19,  5,  4, 32, 33, 13,  1,  2, 16]]) 
# a.shape[0]*a.shape[1]=36 in your case
```

Finally, you take the elements corresponding to the selected indices on the flatten() matrix

```
a.flatten()[0,selected]
```

**Edit**

There is also a direct method based on [numpy.matrix.A1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.A1.html)

```
a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(220,376, size=(6,6)))
elements = np.random.choice(a.A1, 10, replace=False)
```

Comment: `flatten` alone does not seem to work if `x` is a `np.matrix`, though, as it seems to be in OP's case. Also, it seems like `choice` allows for duplicates, which may not be what OP wants (not sure, though).

Comment: Nice... and if `x` is a `np.matrix`, then `np.array(x).flatten()` seems to work.

Comment: Thank you very much.I used my previous code and tried to flatten it. But there is something wrong. Please help me out.
import numpy as np
from numpy import random
rows = 6
cols = 6
a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(220,376, size=(rows,cols)))
np.fill_diagonal(a,0)
print (a)
np.array((a).flatten(),10, replace=False)

Output gives an error message;
TypeError                                 Traceback
<ipython-input-120-94177c27aee1> in <module>()
      3 
      4 
----> 5 np.array((a).flatten(),10, replace=False)
TypeError: data type not understood